# Issues with my JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote a little script to generate a random `yes` or `no`. However, it is not running. At all. What is wrong with my code?

Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u8ukp/

My code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Should You? | A completely random decision</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function func(){
        var i = Math.random();
        if (i >= 0.5) {
            var e = document.getElementById('result');
            e.InnerHTML = "Yes! :)";
        }else{
            var e = document.getElementById('result');
            e.InnerHTML = "Nope! :("
        };
    };
</script>
</head>
<body>
<header>Should You?</header>
<br><br>
<a onclick="func();">Should You?</a>
<br><br>
<span id="result"></span>
 </body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: The problem is how jsFiddle wraps your code. It would work fine in a real webpage.

Comment: I did look at the console.

Comment: Did you read what I said? Here is it fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/u8ukp/4/ It's because you have *onLoad* selected in jsFiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`innerHTML`, not `InnerHTML` -- Javascript is case-sensitive.

[Here's a working JSBin](http://jsbin.com/uVIJOco/1/edit)

Comment: Thanks... but it didn't help. :(

Answer (score 0):

It is a number of things actually. First `innerHTML` and not `InnerHTML`.
Second, not use `<span>` but `<div>`, and last, at the fiddle 'onLoad' was selected, making it impossible to debug.

Comment: Why would it make a difference to use a div tag instead of a span tag?